# Create an empty dictionary, [NSDictionary dictionary] vs @{}, [NSArray array] vs @[], [NSString string] vs @""

Tags: objective-c

`[NSDictionary dictionary]` is the same that `@{}` in terms of memory usage?

Which one should I use?

This same logic applies to `[NSArray array]`/`@[]` or `[NSString string]`/`@""`?

Thanks!

Comment: One is nothing more than a convenience for the other. Syntactic sugar.

Comment: Even if they weren't equivalent: why would you worry? Did you benchmark your code? Did you find that creating dictionaries and arrays eats up tremendous amounts of your memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter which you use, they are effectively the same.

[Read more about it on LLVM.org](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)